# add tag for gitlab branch after merge request approve and merged

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci

1. we want to add a tag **after** merge_request approve/**merged** in default develop branch
2. after add this dev version tag, we also want to do source code complie
3. once complie passed, save target build to local server for test purpose.

seems gitlab still not official support it, is there any unofficial API or good solution to do it?

the most important part is how to trigger this job **after** merge_requst.

Thanks

Comment: If you are also using gitlab CI you could add a build step that is only executed on the master branch and is triggered after the merge is done. In this Build, you could do all these changes.

Comment: thank you very much, job only executed on master branch is easy to do, but how to triggered after the merge request is done? this is my question and the most important part in my question.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this flow I would suggest the following general approach:

1. create a job that `only` runs on `develop` branch and creates a git tag: `git tag $TAG_NAME && git push --tags`
2. create another job that also `only` runs on the `develop` branch, but `needs` the job from point 1 and does the code compiling
3. create a third job that `needs` job from point 2, `only` runs on `develop` and copies the artifact via `scp`, `sftp` or similar method to the local server you mentioned.

The essential part is running the CI job on the `develop` branch as this is the only option to hook into after the merge.

Some documentation that will help you create the specific solution you need:

- `only` -> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except
- `needs` -> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs
- about ssh (sftp/scp) on gitlab -> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-shell-executor
- `git tag` -> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag
- `git push` -> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push
- about `git push` in gitlab-ci -> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/tags.html

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but which action trigger this job?  this is the most important part. as a normal CI job, it can be traigger by push with merge_request, for example:  
```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
```
 or
```
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    variables:
       - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"
```